# Laravel を SPA 化するには？ウェブアプリを改修したいと思っています

Tags: php, reactjs, ajax, websocket, next.js

タイトルにSPA 化するにはと書きましたが、実際にはそれ以前の段階の「どの技術・ライブラリを使用すべきか？」が質問の趣旨となります。

現在、ウェブアプリとして掲示板サービスを運営しています。
いわゆる従来型のMPA（multi page app）なのですが、以下のように変更を加えたいと考えています。

① 投稿をAjax で行う
② 新しい投稿があったら差分のみを取得し画面を自動更新する（WebSocket？）
③ ページ遷移の際にページ全体を更新せずに差分のみ更新する（SPAのような）

上記①～③のように作り直す場合、どのような技術を選定すればよいでしょうか？
調べていると、React, Next.js, SPA, SSR, SSG, など様々なワードが飛び交い、決めあぐねています。

また、①,②は変更範囲がアプリの一部にとどまりますが、③はそれが全体に及びます。
そのため、これは最悪後回しにするか、一部のページのみに適用できればよいと考えています。
ページングのときに差分だけ取得する、検索の際に結果だけ差分として取得するなど。

これらはフロント側での実装になるかと思いますが、開発にあたってはバックエンドとの相性の問題もあるかと思います。
バックエンドでは Laravel 9 を使用しています。
Ajax はいいねボタンなどすでに一部の機能で取り入れていますが、Fetch などの処理をバニラのJS で書いて実装しています。
これも今回の変更に合わせてReact を使うならReact で書き換えるなどしたいと考えています。

①～③の要件を満たすフレームワーク？ライブラリ？はあるのでしょうか。
それとも複数のライブラリを使うことになりますか？
実際の開発ではこのような場合どのような技術選定になるかご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 正直いただいた3つの要件を見ても特に変わったものはなくごく一般的なSPAシステムのようです。特定のライブラリやフレームワークや技術でないと実現できないということはないでしょう。つまりは要件で技術選定をするのは難しいので別の要素で検討してよいかなとおもいました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。採用するなら、Reactとnext.js のどちらかでしょうか？またVue とnuxt.jsもありますが、世界的なシェアがReactの方が大きいのでVue系は使わない方向で考えています。

Comment: その選定をするための情報が足りません。技術選定はプロダクトの未来を決める重要な作業です。開発や保守メンバーの習得度、プロダクトの性質、プロジェクトの予算やスケジュールあらゆる要素で検討する必要があります。CTOや事業責任者と相談して決めたほうがよいでしょう

Comment: 個人プロダクトなので大丈夫です。SPA、JSフレームワークの経験はほとんどありませんので、どれを選んでも学びながらになります。

Comment: 制約がないのであれば好きなものやりたいことをやればいいのではないですか